# Java main class extending another one

Tags: java, abstract-class, javac

I'm having a problem compiling and running the Java class containing my main method. My code is similar to:

```
public import myLib.LibClass;

public class MyMainClass extends LibClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
    @override
    public void LibClassFunction(){...}
}
```

In which LibClass is an abstract class coming from an already compiled .jar file, of which I have to implement a specific abstract function. I can compile without problems with

```
javac -cp ./myLib.jar MyMainClass.java
```

However, I'm not managing to run it with the "java" command, getting the error 
`Error: Could not find or load main class MyMainClass`, even if MyMainClass doesn't have any package.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try adding directory, in which `MyMainClass` resides, to classpath after a colon -- `javac -cp ./myLib.jar:. MyMainClass.java`

Comment: You are not able to run it with what command line?

Comment: Are you sure this compiles?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino The OP has clearly stated that he can compile, and the `-cp`option has nothing to do with the location of source files.

Comment: Adding the directory doesn't fix the error. I'm using bash on ubuntu 16.04. And yes, it compiles, the .class file is generated and no errors or warnings are issued by javac

Comment: What I noticed is that if MyMainClass does not extend the abstract class, the problem is gone (even if the import is still there). I guess extending the main class changes somehow the name I have to use for the java command.

Comment: **What** Java command? That is the only point at issue, and you haven't provided it, or answered it when asked.

Comment: @EJP `java MyMainClass` (same result with `java -cp . MyMainClass`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line you need is

```
java -cp myLib.jar:. MyMainClass
```

You need to provide the stuff that your class depends on.

Separator should be `;`, not `:`, on Unix, Linux, HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, etc.

Comment: `Separator should be ;, not :, on Unix, Linux, HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, etc.` uhhh, are you sure it's not the other way around? Windows has `;`